# Ben Awad vid tutorial problemwith npx mikro-orm migration:create

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, mikro-orm

I'm following the tutorial step by step, when I get to the part of run `npx mikro-orm migration:create`, I get this error

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received null`

````
    at prepareSecretKey (internal/crypto/keys.js:322:11)
    at new Hmac (internal/crypto/hash.js:113:9)
    at Object.createHmac (crypto.js:147:10)
    at createHMAC (C:\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:133:17)
    at Hi (C:\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:137:13)
    at Object.continueSession (C:\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:32:24)
    at Client._handleAuthSASLContinue (C:\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:248:10)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at C:\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:109:12
    at Parser.parse (C:\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:102:9)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:298:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)```

I can't find any solution on google, and the tut doesn't point out how to login to postgresql on the app
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing some configuration, most probably `user` or `password` fields. Here is related issue:

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/866

If you do not provide them, MikroORM will pick the defaults for given driver, which is `postgres` user and empty password - your postgres installation apparently do not have empty password for this user.

If you are using docker to create the postgres server, this is how you can make it accept empty pws:

```
  postgre:
    image: postgres:12.4
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust   <-- here
```

Comment: OH! now I get it, I need to populate the mikro-orm config to access the db, right? I think the tut is implying that doxker is connecting with postgres, so he doesn't talks about it. but can I access it from the `config` via: `{username: 'postgress', password: superpassword}` ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have not specified the `password` or `user` property of an object which you are passing inside of `MikroORM.init`.

This should work

```
export default {
  entities: [Entity],
  dbName: "yourDatabaseName",
  type: "postgresql",
  user: "yourUserName",
  password: "yourPassword"
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];
```